# Simplify $\arcsin (\cos (2x)), 0 \leq x \leq (\pi/2)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Simplify $\arcsin (\cos (2x)), 0 \leq x \leq (\pi/2)$

**My answer:**

I used the identity $\sin ((\pi/2) - x) = \cos x$ and I got $(\pi/2) - 2x$. Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\arcsin(\cos2x)=\dfrac\pi2-\arccos(\cos2x)$$

As $0\le2x\le\pi$ using [Principal values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values)

$$\arccos(\cos2x)=2x$$

If $\pi<2x\le2\pi,\arccos(\cos2x)=2\pi-2x$

If  $-\pi<2x<0,\arccos(\cos2x)=-2x$

Comment: Is my answer correct?

Comment: @hopefully, Observe that I've reached at the same value

Comment: what if $0 \leq 2x \leq \pi$ arccos(cos 2x) equals what?

Comment: why you did not use the identity that I used?

Comment: @hopefully, As it is easier manage with $$\arccos(\cos(...))$$  or $$\arcsin(\sin(...))$$

Comment: @hopefully Lab's answer explicitly states that if $0 \leq 2x \leq \pi$, then $\arccos(2x) = 2x$.  Moreover, in that interval $\arcsin(\cos 2x) = \frac{\pi}{2} - \arccos(\cos 2x) = \frac{\pi}{2} - 2x$.

Comment: So the identity that I used is also correct in the given interval of the problem ....correct?